# How to authenticate via yahoo using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, yahoo-api

Following steps from [Oath Authorization Flow for yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/), i constructed the required url to request token:
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_nonce=ce2130523f788f313f76314ed3965ea6&oauth_timestamp=1202956957&oauth_consumer_key=123456891011121314151617181920&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_signature=abcdef&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref="en-us"&oauth_callback="http://yoursite.com/callback"

Next step requires to post another request by parsing values from response of  the previous request. How to parse that response? The response is of the following format:

oauth_token=bvtrm6e&oauth_token_secret=0c31b2206817c08e3e21b8179fdf207d6967cecd&oauth_expires_in=3600&xoauth_request_auth_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.login.yahoo.com%2Foauth%2Fv2%2Frequest_auth%3Foauth_token%3Dbvtrm6e&oauth_callback_confirmed=true

Answer (score 0):

The function posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) worked well for me. It shouldn't be too hard to get this if you're performing the operation server side. However, I am not sure that it's possible to get the response purely through Javascript.